# Trigger to create a partially unique identifier

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite database with a table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        uuid varchar(500),
        email text NOT NULL,
        display_name text NOT NULL,
        puid text,
        password text NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE (email),
        CONSTRAINT rid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);
```

loooks something like

```
9c8eb712-4c9b-4d37-b901-a7e14be6e3af|fake@email.net|fakename|67ba|Tnetennba
```

currently i have a trigger that creates a UUID for the uuid value in this table whenever an insert happens.

but I'm trying to create a trigger that creates the puid (player unique identifier) where it checks if another entry in the users table contains both the same display_name and PUID so it does not create the same PUID again.

the reason i want two different UUIDs is that PUID is a 2 byte hex number '67ba' while UUID is massive. so i want PUID to be used for example in a friend list for a multiplayer game where you can have display_name#puid because i don't want people to see the message "this username already exists"

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoGeneratePUID_RELATION_3
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.puid IS NULL)
BEGIN
        UPDATE users SET puid = (select lower(hex( randomblob(2)))) WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

is what i currently have, but this does not check the validity of the puid against the other entries with the same display_name. so how would i go about checking if puid is already in use by another entry with the same display_name.

If anything here doesn't make sense, please let me know i have dyslexia and English isn't my native language.

Comment: *how would i go about checking if puid is already in use by another entry with the same display_name* What do you want to happen if it is already in use by by another entry with the same display_name or another entry with a different display_name?

Comment: @forpas `What do you want to happen if it is already in use by by another entry with the same display_name or another entry with a different display_name?`

i want it to generate a new PUID if another already exists with the same display name, otherwise keep it as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop that generates random blobs until you get one that does not already exist for the inserted `display_name`.
This can be done with a recursive CTE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AutoGeneratePUID_RELATION_3
AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.puid IS NULL)
BEGIN
   UPDATE users 
   SET puid = (
     with cte as (
       select lower(hex(randomblob(2))) puid, 1 level 
       union all 
       select lower(hex(randomblob(2))), c.level + 1
       from cte c
       where exists (select 1 from users where display_name = NEW.display_name and puid = c.puid)
     )
     select distinct first_value(puid) over (order by level desc)
     from cte
   ) 
   WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```